# How to run function for every browser request made?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a v3 manifest chrome extension that runs the background worker script once the extension is installed.
I want this script to be ran every time a request is made in the browser.
In v2 manifest I was using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener().
This is the code so far for the extension:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Daniel Website Blocker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Block a list of websites",
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [ "ContentScript.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "host_permissions" : [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [ {
    "resources": ["images/*"],
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
  }],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```
const url = 'https://6459308c8badff578e071356.mockapi.io/sitelist/websites';

async function getJSONData() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {

  var data = await getJSONData();
  console.log("data from the api call is",data);
    const rules = data.map((website) => {
      return {
        "id": parseInt(website.id),
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {
          "type": "block"
        },
        "condition": {
          "urlFilter": website.name,
          "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
        }
      };
    });
  console.log("the final list is:",rules);
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    "addRules": rules,
    removeRuleIds: rules.map(item => item.id)
  });
});
```

I want to change "chrome.runtime.onInstalled" with something to run for every request.
I don't have any other files, I just want to block sites from a list given via an API call, but the list can change.

Thanks!

Comment: I have an endpoint with a list of blockes websites, block start time and for how long. I want the extension to block the websites from the list and make an API call back to the end point for each request when no site is blocked, in case a new list appears at the endpoint.

Comment: In that case declarativeNetRequest is the correct solution for blocking. You can improve it further if your websites are just domains without paths: make a single rule and use them in `requestDomains`, no need for urlFilter. For observing non-blocked requests simply keep your old webRequest code.